# How to correctly

Tags: bash, shell, hadoop, scripting, vagrant

I have the following example of a `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

## vagrant-hostmanager-start
<ipaddress1>   namenode
<ipaddress2> secondarynamenode
<ipaddress3>   slave1
<ipaddress4>  slave2
< it can be more slave nodes here>
## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

As I'm trying to configure a hadoop cluster, I need to split the `/etc/hosts` file in the following configuration:

1. `namenode` and `secondarynamenode` go to a file called `masters`
2. `slaves*` go to a file called `slaves`
3. There will be at least the `namenode`, and 0 or more slaves.

What's the easiest way to parse that file as mentioned in `bash`, and write the parts to the respective parts as mentioned (`masters` and `slaves`)? I could do it easily in `Python`, but I need it done in `bash`. 
`masters` would look like:

```
    <ipaddress1>   namenode
    <ipaddress2> secondarynamenode
```

while `slaves` be like:

```
    <ipaddress3>   slave1
    <ipaddress4>  slave2
```

Comment: Do you need the whole line to be in each file or only the ip addresses?

Comment: @NotANumber the whole line ... but only the ip address will do it ..

Comment: And the <ipaddress1> patterns will actually be replace by real ip numbers, right? or will you also have alphanumeric strings there?

Comment: @NotANumber just numbers for the ipaddress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '/namenode/{print >"masters"; next} /slave[0-9]/{print > "slaves"}' /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, to do it right, you have to ensure that comments containing "slave" and "namenode" are ignored. I think this will work.

```
sed -n "/namenode/ s/^\([0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*\)  *s*[a-z]*namenode.*/\1/gp" /etc/hosts > masters
sed -n "/slave/ s/^\([0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*.[0-9][0-9]*\)  *slave.*/\1/gp" /etc/hosts  > slaves
```

To get the whole line would be the same, but replace the /\1/ with /&/.

The answer provided by anubhava will also work, but could deliver wrong strings, specially if the IP address has an error such as 127.0.0.d1.